# How to round off the coordinates of gejson object in pydantic

Tags: python, coordinates, geojson, pydantic

I am currently working on python version 3.10.6 in which I want to round off the coordinates decimal points to the 6 digits only. Instead of using for loop and iterating through each line, I want to do it at base level i.e. lat and lon of the Polygon.

Here I want to round off to 6 decimal points of Polygon's coordinates(lat and lon of CustomCoordinates).

```
LonField = Annotated[
    Union[float, float],
    Field(
        title='Coordinate longitude',
        gt=-180,
        lt=180,
    )
]

LatField = Annotated[
    Union[float, float],
    Field(
        title='Coordinate latitude',
        gt=-90,
        lt=90,
    ),
]


class CustomCoordinates(NamedTuple):
    lat: LatField
    lon: LonField


class PolygonGeo(CamelModel):
    type: Optional[str] = Field(None, description='Type of GeoJSon geometry', example='Polygon')
    coordinates: Optional[List[List['CustomCoordinates']]] = Field(
        None, description='Coordinates of GeoJSon geometry', example='[[[-73.7786925003853,40.63992777725],...]]]')
```

I have imported the pydantic_geojson which provides the inbuilt geometry classes.
But I want to modify the coordinates i.e. rounding off to 6 decimal places.
I have tried

```
LonField = Annotated[
    Union[float, float],
    Field(
        title='Coordinate longitude',
        decimal_places=6,
        gt=-180,
        lt=180,
    )
]
```

I get the below error

```
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 198, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 506, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 436, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 552, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 661, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 758, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 808, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._create_sub_type
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 436, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 552, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 758, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 808, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._create_sub_type
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 436, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 557, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 831, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.populate_validators
  File "pydantic\validators.py", line 735, in find_validators
  File "pydantic\validators.py", line 599, in pydantic.validators.make_namedtuple_validator
  File "pydantic\annotated_types.py", line 72, in pydantic.annotated_types.create_model_from_namedtuple
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 1026, in pydantic.main.create_model
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 198, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 504, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic\schema.py", line 1011, in pydantic.schema.get_annotation_from_field_info
ValueError: On field "lon" the following field constraints are set but not enforced: decimal_places. 
For more details see https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#unenforced-field-constraints
```

Also, I have tried this but it's not rounding it off.

```
class CustomCoordinates(NamedTuple):
    lat: LatField
    lon: LonField

    @validator('lat')
    def coordinates_roundOff(cls,v):
        return round(v, 6)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post include the exact error, and make sure to use code markup so any alignment is preserved.

Comment: I have edited the post, and I hope it clarifies the problem.

Comment: And you've read through the URL it tells you to read? Because the code shown for describing fields does not look like the code you're showing.